# How to schedule content every Wednesday at 18.00 (6 PM)?

Tags: 8, rules, cron, queue

Looking for something which was easy in Drupal 7, but can't find it or can't get it to work in Drupal 8.

1. import feed
2. do not publish content immediately
3. run a rule that sets the content to publish every Wednesday at 18.00 (6 PM)

Any suggestions how to do this in Drupal 8?

I've tried:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduled_publish
- https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduled_updates
- https://www.drupal.org/project/moderation_scheduler
- https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler
- https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules
- https://www.drupal.org/project/rules (seemed obvious I already tried that)
- and other stuff that I already forgot since I've been trying this for
  several weeks now ...

And only Scheduler came close (as I used it in Drupal 7).

Where does it fail?
When making the rule (after saving new content ...):

- it does not allow me to use 'wednesday 18:00' but instead I need to
  use a 'unix timestamp', which means I need to change it every week
- and even if I use a 'unix timestamp' the 'schedule options' tab stays
  blank (if I insert a date when manually creating the content it
  works)

After testing the business rules module for two days I'm starting to suspect the problem is Drupal itself: it's simply not excepting anything except unix timestamps.

I tried making a field with php code to calculate 'wednesday 18:00', tried it with strotime, ... all to no avail. I have some hope this could still work, but my coding skills are to limited.

So ... any other options? (I'm not a developer, can't build custom modules.)

Comment: look for 'business rules module' in D8

Comment: Thank you for the tip, interesting module and looked promising but same problems. I'll update my question.

Comment: Try Rules and rules_scheduler included submodule or create custom module which looks at custom field to take action periodically

Comment: First thing I tried was rules and submodules.I can't make modules, they would probably large security holes. I tried a custom field as mentioned (php, strotime) in my post, but could not produce the unix timestamp. And that's the only thing Drupal 8 seems to accept.

Comment: Is it you are asking "How can I implement a recurring schedule publishing all unpublished content at a certain time every week?" What a pity you can't code. Actually it's pretty easy. `hook_cron` to fetch all unpublished node IDs weekly and then pass them to a QueueWorker (**Queue API**) to publish them.

Comment: Here's a really brilliant article about exactly that: https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-queue-api-powerful-manual-and-cron-queueing/

Comment: Yes, leymannx, that is what I'm asking. I'll have a look at the article. Sorry, my responses are slow. I work in a hospital and as you can imagine we have other priorities right now.